Get cookies of the page QWebEngineView Python
I'm creating a browser in Python and I would like to know how to recover the cookies from the web page, no matter how much I search I don't understand how it is possible
This is my code :
nav = QWebEngineView()
nav.load(QUrl(url))

I would like someone to explain to me how to recover the cookies.

Get the default profile using QWebEngineProfile.defaultProfile(), it returns a QWebEngineProfile object. Get the cookie using profile.cookieStore(), it returns a QWebEngineCookieStore object. Then connect cookieAdded from the cookie store to a slot and this slot will be called every time a cookie is added. Then just do whatever you want with the cookie:
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView, QWebEngineProfile
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl

def handle_cookie_added(cookie):
    print("Cookie added:", cookie.name(), cookie.value())
nav = QWebEngineView()
nav.load(QUrl(url))
profile = QWebEngineProfile.defaultProfile()
cookie_store = profile.cookieStore()
cookie_store.cookieAdded.connect(handle_cookie_added)

